dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-8-local_11.8.0-1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe:
so i am installing cuda 11.8 through windows wsl2 but in the fourth line 1(the fourth line) im getting this error dpkg-deb: error:  subprocess returned error exit status 2 please help me
thank you

Perhaps the downloaded .deb file is incomplete or corrupted? You can find the checksum here
